# Cambios en archivos JS dan errores para actualizarse, Causa?

Tags: javascript

Cada vez que edito mis archivos javascript y reviso la consola del navegador no se cambian, tengo que cerrar y abrir muchas veces mi navegador, incluso borrar el cache con CONTROL+SHIFT+R y hasta cortar y pegar el archivo para ver los cambios, que puedo hacer para que se activen los cambios de una forma mas rapida o en su defecto que problema genera esa dificultad para actualizar?

Tratando de editar este archivo JS me da problemas diciendo que la funcion Documentar no es una funcion

```
function zoom() {
document.body.style.zoom = "125%" 
}

function cambiando() {
document.getElementById("cambio").value = 1;
document.cambiar_contrasena.submit();
}

function documentar() {
alert("hola");
}

function loginConectar() {
document.getElementById("conectar").value = 1;
document.index.submit();
}

function loginFocus() {
document.getElementById("txtusuario").focus();
}

function generarOMD() {
document.getElementById("generando").value = 1;
document.omd.submit();
}

function buscarOMD1() {
document.getElementById("buscando").value = 1;
document.buscar_omd.submit();
}

function buscarOMD2() {
document.getElementById("buscando").value = 1;
document.buscar_omd.submit();
}

function registrarUsuario() {
document.getElementById("registrando").value = 1;
document.registrarusuario.submit();
}

function restaurarContrasena() {
document.getElementById("restaurando").value = 1;
document.restaurarusuario.submit();
}
```

A veces debo cambiar muchas veces los nombres de las funciones porque dicen que no son funciones:

> Uncaught TypeError: documentar is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

y al cambiarles el nombre sirven, que puede generar este problema?

documentar es llamado en una tabla que genera columnas automaticamente mediante registros en una base de datos:

```
<td width="25"><input type="button" name="ver" id="ver" value="Ver" onclick="documentar();"></td></tr>
```

Tuve que cambiar el nombre de la funcion a hola() y en el JS function hola()

Comment: Respecto al error, ¿podrías poner el código en donde llamas a `documentar`? Sobre el caché, abre la consola web y ve hacia la sección Network. Aquí mira la petición del fichero JS y mira sin dice "from cache".

Comment: accionesSistema.js 200 script acciones_consultar_omd_unidades.php 1.9 KB 7 ms

Sale esto y se carga al entrar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes desactivar la cache del navegador o bien añadir al final de la carga de tu fichero javascript una variable que vaya cambiando.

Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?v=1"></script>
```

Al aplicar un cambio sobre el fichero `myfile.js` modifico la linea

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?v=2"></script>
```

Comment: lo que hice fue agregarle un alert("hola") luego ("hola cambie") y asi

Comment: pues tienes dos opciones:
1- desactivar cache
2- añadir una variable que cambie cada vez que haces un cambio.

Comment: es por momentos que le da la locura jejeje