# ¿Cómo forzar la carga del cache de un solo archivo JS?

Tags: javascript, navegador-web, cache

He visto varias preguntas similares, pero ninguna responde exactamente a lo que necesito.
Tengo un menú web realizado en JavaScript para no tener que estar actualizando a mano todos los enlaces en todas las páginas. Esto es muy útil. Sin embargo, tengo el problema de la caché, hasta que no caduca en los navegadores de los usuarios (creo que lo tengo en 30 días si no me equivoco), no les van a aparecer los nuevos enlaces debido a la caché del navegador.

He visto algunas soluciones indicando que se evite guardar archivos en caché, pero eso no es lo que quiero, solo quiero evitar el archivo js con el menú y no todo.

También he visto lo de añadir al nombre de archivo algo como v1, v2, etc. para que se considere un nuevo archivo por el navegador, no obstante, esta solución no me sirve, ya que tendría que estar renombrando el nombre del archivo en todas las páginas después de cada cambio.

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57680/54039), es suficiente con agregar un parámetro, algo como `<script src="/ruta/archivo.js?upd=20220310"></script>`

Comment: Hola, no me sirve, porque si tengo el menú en 1000 páginas, en cada página tendré que modificar el atributo src.

Comment: Quizás con algún tipo de expresión regular que obtenga el valor actual de la fecha o algo así, y de los valores que dices en el src, pero no sé como hacerlo. Si encuentro la forma, comentaré.

Comment: La modificación no debe ser manual, un buen editor o IDE como Sublime Text o Visual Studio Code te permiten abrir carpetas y modificar todas las coincidencias. El único "inconveniente" es que vas a tener que subir todos los archivos modificados.